# Connecting Appium to Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, grid

I'm having trouble connecting Appium to our local Grid.

When I try to connect I don't get any errors, but I do not see Appium in the Grid console.

Here's my node config file.

```
{
     "capabilities":
     [
        {
            "browserName":“iPhone5”,
            "version”:”6.1,
            "maxInstances": 1,
            "platform”:”MAC”
        }
    ],
    "configuration":
    {
        "cleanUpCycle":2000,
        "timeout":30000,
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "url":"http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub",
        "host": “127.0.0.1”,
        "port": 4723,
        "maxSession": 1,
        "register": true,
        “hubPort: 4444,
        “hubHost”: “192.168.28.74”:

    }
}
```

Has anyone had any success connecting Appium to their own Grid?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/1704

Answer (score 1):

There is a quote in front of the version. if you take it off your code should work
i.e "version”:”6.1 should be "version”:6.1,

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the node config file is not formatted correctly (should be a valid JSON file).

the `"version":"6.1"` the value should be string, and the `“hubHost”: “192.168.28.74”:` <--- shouldn't contain colon after the host hub address.

And IMO you should define: `"hub": "http://<address>:<port>/grid/register",` too on the configuration area.

here is some example of a valid node config:

```
 {
     "capabilities": [
         {
             "browserName": "Android",
             "version": "4.4",
             "maxInstances": 1,
             "platform": "ANDROID",
             "deviceName": "08b8c683"
         }
     ],
     "configuration": {
         "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
         "timeout": 300,
         "browserTimeout": 300,
         "hub": "http://localhost:4444/grid/register",
         "host": "localhost",
         "maxSession": 1,
         "port": 4733,
         "hubPort": 4444,
         "hubHost": "localhost",
         "url": "http://localhost:4733/wd/hub",
         "register": true,
         "registerCycle": 5000,
         "role": "node"
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You config file looks correct.

Please verify that you've installed and configured Appium correctly, according to [this official tutorial for Mac OS](http://appium.io/tutorial/).